# Defining many function values elegantly in haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I want to define a function that will capitalize all lowercase letters:

```
yell :: Char -> Char
yell 'a' = 'A'
yell 'b' = 'B'
...
yell 'z' = 'Z'
yell ch = ch
```

What's the best way to do this? I can make a list of pairs of the appropriate inputs and outputs via `zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z']` but I'm not sure how to turn this into a definition of `yell`.

I know that `lookup` is something of an option but then I have to futz with `Maybe`, and I wonder if there is anything even more elementary available.

Comment: `yell c | 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' = toUpper c` (with `toUpper` from `Data.Char`)?

Comment: The reason you have to futz with `Maybe` in `lookup` is because the input might not be in the list. "Look this item up and if it's not in the input list leave it alone" it not a terribly elementary thing, especially since functions often have different input and output types. Anyway futzing with maybe is not hard at all: `yell ch = fromMaybe ch (lookup ch (zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z']))`

Comment: And if writing your own version of `lookup` using recursion doesn't sound incredibly routine and boring yet, I would recommend it as an instructive exercise. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a guard, and make use of [**`toUpper :: Char -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toUpper), of the [**`Data.Char`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html) for example:

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)

yell :: Char -> Char
yell c
    | 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' = toUpper c
    | otherwise = c
```

for ASCII characters, the uppercase is just masking out the sixth bit (with `0010 0000` as mask). So `toUpper` is equivalent to `chr . (~0x20 .&.) . ord` for that specific range.

There are however other characters that have an uppercase variant such as characters with diacritics (`àáâãäåæçèéêëìí…`), Greek characters (`αβγδεζηθικλ…`), fullwidth characters (`ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈ…`), etc. These are all converted with `toUpper`, and can not (all) be converted with this trick.

You can perform a lookup with a lookup structure, like for example a `

```
import Data.HashMap.Strict(HashMap, fromList)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

items :: HashMap Char Char
items = fromList (zip ['a' .. 'z'] ['A' .. 'Z'])

yell :: Char -> Char
yell c
    | Just y <- HM.lookup c items = y
    | otherwise = c
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I could have made my question clearer, but I'm still interested in knowing how to define many function values using a list of pairs. I wanted to give a concrete example to work with but perhaps because it involved characters it was too concrete and the part I'm interested in is swept under the `toUpper` in your answer.

Comment: @Diffycue Then you should edit your question to have an example that a built-in function doesn't already do.

Comment: @Diffycue: that is an algorithm that contains several rules for several ranges of unicode. I'm quite convinced that it is not a lookup table, since there are ~1000 characters with a different uppercase variant, that would thus make it rather large. But anyway, I incuded an example how you can make use of a `HashMap` for example to perform a lookup. Using a list of 2-tuples will be rather inefficient I think (well perhaps not for `a`-`z`, but definitely if you want to map a larger amount of data).

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thank you for the suggestion, but it is likely to be only partially implemented since when I know the complete catalogue of functions for the built-in Haskell modules I will be asking different sorts of questions from the ones I am now. And in spite of the existence of `toUpper` Willem has offered a very clear solution.